# How to run a .sql file with phppgadmin or psql

Tags: postgresql, phppgadmin

While importing .sql file in phppgadmin it produces an error

> "Import error: Failed to automatically determine the file format".

How to import the file?

And in terminal it shows as

```
postgres-# \i Documents/sample.sql

Documents/sample.sql: No such file or directory
```

But the file exists in the particular location. How to import .sql file in Postgresql and in Phppgadmin

Comment: it supports .sql file

Comment: Your relative path probably doesn't work from the current directory. `\i` **does** work with SQL scripts. Try to supply the **full** path to the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by command line:

Get login with your psql through command line and
just run the following command in your terminal

```
psql 'databasename' < 'database_dump'
```

just replace 'databasename' with your database and 'database_dump' with the file you want to import.

Comment: will "psql 'databasename' < 'database_dump'"  work importing a .sql file

Comment: By using this codepostgres-# psql postgres < ../Music/datahere.sql

Comment: it doesnot produce any error but do data is imported in phppgadmin

Comment: what's the name of your database?

Comment: postgres is the name of the database

Comment: then check the path of your sql file, there must some issue

Comment: You are welcome, you can also upvote the answer, that will be really helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

You can run a file using below command

> psql -U postgres -d postgres -a -f ./test.sql

or if you have to pass a host

> psql -h  -p 5432 -U postgres -d  -a -f ./test2.sql

[You can refer this blog](https://trueway-blog.com/run-sql-file-with-psql/) https://trueway-blog.com/run-sql-file-with-psql/